# Add firewall exception in remote Windows machine using C++

Tags: c++, windows-firewall

Is there a way in `C++` by which I can add a `firewall exception` to a port in a remote `Windows` machine? I tried the code given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364726%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). But it works only for local machine. If I have the `IP`, `username` and `password` of remote machine how can I do it?

Comment: At least if things work the way they're supposed to, you should only be able to modify the firewall from the inside. So, the first thing you need to do is load your program onto the target machine, and get it to execute there. To do that, you need a hole through the firewall, so the first step to set up your firewall exception is to already have a firewall exception...

Comment: @JerryCoffin: you mean i have to copy the exe for adding firewall exception to the remote machine and execute it??No other way??

Comment: Well, we'll hope not, anyway (a firewall that can be modified from the outside sounds pretty weak).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Ya..it sounds weak..But, wont there be some way  by which network administrators does this?I hope YES!!

Comment: @Jackz: NO!! Direct manipulation of a remote firewall is a security risk. If the network admin does not have direct access to the firewall machine, the only safe option is to use a client-server model, where the server is running on the firewall machine with admin rights, has a hole open in the firewall to accept a client connection, and then the client can send commands to the server and the server can manipulate the firewall accordingly. A client cannot manipulate a remote firewall directly (unless you are a hacker who knows how!).

Comment: @RemyLebeau , JerryCoffin : Now that I created an exe to add a port exception. If the firewall is on in the remote machine, how will I run the exe as a service there :(

Comment: You would have to install and run your .exe on that machine, obviously.  You cannot run it from your local machine and have it operate on the remote machine, it has to be run locally on the remote machine. You can use something like [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to run a .exe file remotely. Or, if it really is a service, you can install it on the remote machine and then connect to that machine's SCM to control its local services.  But the .exe still needs to reside on the remote machine either way.